# How to reverse values of keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse

So i have this dict:

```
role_positions = {role1: 1, role2: 2, role3: 3}
```

How do i reverse the values of it? like this:

```
role_positions = {role1: 3, role2: 2, role3: 1}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Note that dicts don’t necessarily have an order, there are a lot of asterisks to the notion of order in a dict. Hence you may just end up *shuffling* the values, not necessarily reversing them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get values as a list then reversed them and zip with keys and return dict like below:

```
# python_version > 3.8
>>> dict(zip(role_positions, reversed(role_positions.values())))
{'role1': 3, 'role2': 2, 'role3': 1}

# python_version < 3.8
>>> dict(zip(role_positions, reversed(list(role_positions.values()))))
```

For older versions of python, for sure about the order of different run-time we need to get the inputted `dict` as `OrderedDict`: ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared) we can read a good explanation)

*We suppose we get `OrderDict` as input, below code is only used for creating `OrderDict`. if we use the below code in the older version maybe we get a different OrderedDict (because `role_positions` maybe get a different order)  but we suppose the user input `OrderDict`*

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# we supoose we input below dict
o_dct = OrderedDict((k, v) for k,v in role_positions.items())
dict(zip(o_dct, reversed(list(o_dct.values()))))
```

Comment: `reversed(...)` will work also without `list()`

Comment: @VPfB, do you check the above code, without a `list`?

Comment: @I'mahdi it will work without `list` (in Python 3.8+) , and also without `.keys()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I got this error: `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not reversible`

Comment: @I'mahdi because you are on a version lower than Python 3.8

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, exactly,

Comment: I made a mistake with the `reversed` comment, `list()` is required for the old but still supported Python 3.7 and I did not know that. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: For versions <3.7 the order of insertion is not preserved and the result will be inconsistent **between runs**.

Comment: @I'mahdi, if you run the script multiple times you will get different result, i,e. different key:value pairs. This will be more evident with dict with more elements

Comment: @buran, Yes you are right if the order of elements in the first dict changed we may have different result

Comment: @I'mahdi, no, in versions < 3.7 the order of insertion is not preserved. i.e. in different runs of the script, the order of elements in the dict may be (and most likely will be) different and the resulting key:value pairs will be different. Test for your self with e.g. version 3.5 and a dict with e.g. 5 key:value pairs, run it several times

Comment: @buran, yes you are right, I know for previous version and sure about order we need to get `collections. OrderedDict`

Comment: @buran, how about editing?

Comment: @I'mahdi, in versions <3.7 the `collections.OrderedDict` has to be used when creating `role_positions`, i.e. it has to be created as `OrderedDict` in order to preserve the order of insertion. What you do will not solve the problem with versions <3.7 because the order in the `role_positions` is not guaranteed and you iterate over dict with "unknown" order.

Comment: @buran, I write exactly, we suppose we get `order_dict` as input if we have older version, I Know creating order_dict generate different order_dict

Comment: Your `o_dict` is created by iterating over `role_positions`. If `role_positions` is created as regular dict this does not solve the problem in <3.7

Comment: @buran, I Know in different run_time we get different order_dict

Comment: @buran, we can not solve in older version only if user input `orderdict`, if use input dict code generate a different result

Comment: @buran, Do you have a solution for the older version? if the user inputs `dict` and we are sure about the order that we want.

Comment: @I'mahdi, the only rule they provide for producing the result is to reverse the order. In <3.7 with regular dict (i.e. unclear/inconsistent order of input)  it is impossible to produce consistent result without further info/rules. This was noted in deceze comment like 50 minutes ago.

Comment: @buran, exactly, I say the same things but if the user inputs `OrderDict` do you believe we can get same order in each run_time and each python_version?

Comment: I already agreed to that - if they create role_positions as ordered dict, they will get consistent result (assuming order of insertion in the OrderedDict is the same, i.e. if there is not some random factor outside their control).

Comment: @buran, exactly ;)